# How to separate two pause times in while loop?

Tags: javascript, graphics, javascript-objects

In my code I am trying to measure the speed of the car and change the color of traffic lights.

However, these two contain different pause times: one is faster while another is too slow. When I write both in my while loop the graphics become too slow or too fast.

How can I separate them from each other?

```
 while (true) {
         if (carRed.getX()+CAR_LENGHT<=xWall.getX()) {
             dx= rgen.nextDouble(-MIN_SPEED,-MAX_SPEED);
             carRed.setLocation(getWidth()-CAR_LENGHT,(SCREEN_HEIGHT/2)-CAR_WIDTH);
         }
         if (carBlue.getY()+CAR_LENGHT>=yWall.getY()) {
             dy= rgen.nextDouble(MIN_SPEED,MAX_SPEED);
             carBlue.setLocation(getWidth()/2-CAR_WIDTH,0);
         }
         carRed.move(dx, 0);
         pause(PAUSE_TIME);
         carBlue.move(0, dy);
         pause(PAUSE_TIME); 
         // lights for the horizontal one.
         int lightOne=rgen.nextInt(1,2);
         colorOfTrafficLightFirst(lightOne);
         // lights for the vertical one.
         int lightTwo=rgen.nextInt(1,2);
         colorOfTrafficLightSecond(lightTwo);
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: extra info : colorOfTrafficLights method is private which contains different pause time than (PAUSE_TIME).

Comment: What do you mean by when you say you want to separate these?